# Set property back to original value on saving in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

In the "SavingChanges" event of the Entity Framework context, is there a way to ignore any changes that were made to a specific field/property?

Specifically, I have a property on my entity "CreatedBy".  I need to set this property in the application, but once it is set (when the entity state is "Added"), I want the property to be available, but do not want anybody to be able to change the value.

Does anyone know how to ignore changes to this field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This code in the "SavingChanges" event handler seems to take care of it.

```
foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in ((ObjectContext)sender).ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified))
        {
            if (!entry.IsRelationship)
            {
                if (entry.GetModifiedProperties().Count(p => p == "CreatedBy") > 0)
                {
                    Guid cb = entry.OriginalValues.GetGuid(entry.OriginalValues.GetOrdinal("CreatedBy"));
                    PropertyInfo createdBy = entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedBy");
                    createdBy.SetValue(entry.Entity, cb, null);
                }
                if (entry.GetModifiedProperties().Count(p => p == "CreatedDate") > 0)
                {
                    DateTime cd = entry.OriginalValues.GetDateTime(entry.OriginalValues.GetOrdinal("CreatedDate"));
                    PropertyInfo createdDate = entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("CreatedDate");
                    createdDate.SetValue(entry.Entity, cd, null);
                }
            }
        }
```